# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, serial-port, mybatis

I looked around this error extensively on Google/MyBatis forums but could not find a definitive answer. I have table defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" 
(
 id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_userid_seq'::regclass),
 username character varying(256) NOT NULL,
 first_name character varying(128),
 last_name character varying(128),
 id_number character varying(32),
 id_type integer,
 email_verified boolean,
 cellphone_verified boolean,
 token character varying(256),
 CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT unique_user_username UNIQUE (username)
)
WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The user_userid_seq is defined as:

```
     CREATE SEQUENCE user_userid_seq
     INCREMENT 1
     MINVALUE 1
     MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
     START 1
    CACHE 1;
```

I use MyBatis generator to generate MapperXML and other classes. However, when I'm trying to insert a record using the auto generated mapper, I get the following error:

```
Error updating database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
  ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint 
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, abc@gmail.com, Edwin, Eliot, 98098098, 1, f, null, null). 
  The error may involve com.dukstra.xxx.web.data.mapper.UserMapper.insert-Inline 
  The error occurred while setting parameters 
    SQL: insert into public.user (id, username, first_name, last_name, id_number, id_type, email_verified, cellphone_verified, token ) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
    ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint 
    Detail: Failing row contains (null, abc@gmail.com, Edwin, Eliot, 98098098, 1, f, null, null).
```

It seems that upon calling 
     mapper.insert(newUser);
the id column is being is passed as null, which causes the error above. What is the best way to fix this? I found several work arounds, but not sure if there is a definitive way? Some solutions suggested specifying an explicit selectKey and setting type to "pre" with the "generatedKey" option. However, this would mean having to write/customize xml for each of the table with a auto generated primary key with sequence. Is there a simpler way to either tell Postgres to automatically use a default key if the value is null or perhaps allow a "DEFAULT" (String) value in the ID field of generated user object?
What is the best way to handle this?

UPDATE: here is the generator config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE configuration
           PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
           "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
     <configuration>
  <settings>
    <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="true" />
   </settings>
    <environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/travelnet" /> 
            <property name="username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="password" value="*******" />

        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>

<mappers>
    <package name="com.dukstra.travelnet.web.data.mapper" />

</mappers>
```

Comment: The default applies only if NO value is provided on insert.  Providing any value, even null, attempts to insert that value.

Comment: What is the value of the config parameter `useGeneratedKeys`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to not pass the **id** column down to the DB when doing an insert. New records will get their **id** values from the sequence which you have there. How exactly you can achieve this with these particular technologies you're using, I am not sure as I have no experience with them. Probably you can do this through the MapperXML or through some annotations in the entity classes which you have.

Answer (score 0):

use BIGSERIAL instead of creating manual sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE "user" 
(
 id BIGSERIAL,
 username character varying(256) NOT NULL,
 first_name character varying(128),
 last_name character varying(128),
 id_number character varying(32),
 id_type integer,
 email_verified boolean,
 cellphone_verified boolean,
 token character varying(256),
 CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT unique_user_username UNIQUE (username)
)
WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);
```